# Gmail App Scripts AddOn: XMLHttpRequest Error

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am developing a Gmail App Scripts Ad-On.  I am able to create cards, and child cards, and add controls to the cards, and it works well.  However, I need to add functionality to make an oData call to a web service in another application.  As soon as I add the following line in my code.gs file I get the error shown below when I run my add-on in Gmail.

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

ReferenceError: "XMLHttpRequest" is not defined. [line: 187, function: gotoChildCard, file: Code]

It never even gets beyond that line, so it is not any problem with oData structure or anything, it does not like that line.  I have tried to find some posts, but I cannot find anything (I did find some people getting this error when they develop a Chrome Extension, but that is different - I am creating a Gmail App Scripts Add-On).  I was thinking that maybe I need to add something to my manifest file, but if so, I do not know what it is.

below is my appscript.json file:

```
`{
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.execute",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
  ],
  "gmail": {
    "name": "Dean's Gmail Add-On:  Multiple Cards for Set ",
    "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/2x/bookmark_black_24dp.png",
    "contextualTriggers": [{
      "unconditional": {
      },
      "onTriggerFunction": "createNavigationCard"
    }],
    "openLinkUrlPrefixes": [
      "https://mail.google.com/"
    ],
    "primaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "secondaryColor": "#4285F4",
    "version": "TRUSTED_TESTER_V2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only make HTTP requests using the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) in Apps Scripts